# alias command stopped working

Tags: macos, command-line, alias

I have a few aliases set up on my mac. But for some reason they don't seem to work anymore. I'm not sure why either. Even when I type in `alias` to see my list of aliases nothing happens just this:

```
Jonnys-MacBook-Air:~ jonny$ alias
Jonnys-MacBook-Air:~ jonny$
```

If I go into my `~/.profile` script with nano I can see the script exists and has values though.

Comment: To troubleshoot this a bit, what happens when you type `alias foo=ls; foo; alias` ? The shell should be working if you get a listing and one alias defined.

Comment: @bmike I got the directory listings, there is an alias.save file listed in there too